# 1999 Accord 2.3l died on the highway. No CEL and the engine never stopped running, but the car wouldn’t move, wouldn’t rev over 1,500 RPM,

Tags: honda, accord

After a while I couldn’t connect to the ECU.

The car drove fine until suddenly slowing to a stop without any warning. Everything on the dash looked fine. Nothing looked out of the ordinary–until I tried to move or rev.

I keep an OBD-II bluetooth dongle plugged in and checked for pending codes as soon as I started losing power. There weren’t any, but when I tried it again Torque just said it couldn’t connect.

Mom drove me home and a tow truck took my car to a shop, but the driver said he drove my car up the ramp, it just hesitated to start.

My mechanic drove her for 10 miles and idled for an hour without an issue. I immediately drove to AutoZone and someone checked my battery and alternator, saying they were working perfectly, but told me to clean the little bit of corrosion on my terminals.

I have driven my car for 4 days without a problem, not even any hesitation on startup.
The car drove fine until suddenly slowing to a stop without any warning. Everything on the dash looked fine. Nothing looked out of the ordinary–until I tried to move or rev.

By the way, she had a quarter tank.

What do I check next?

Thank you very much! Have a great day!

Comment: Are you saying that this issue happened once and that now the car is behaving correctly?

Comment: 1999?  Hmmm. The state of technology for powertrain control module (PCM) and fault codes wasn’t perfect. I’m not so experienced with Honda, but I know elsewhere there are failures that could occur and not set a code. That’s where you have to be looking. My guess is ignition module and/or wiring. Have you done the simple dark of night, headlights off, open hood, look for ground out sparks? And a verification test. If you ran engine with one plug wire disconnected would a code get set?

Comment: Other things to check?  Badly worn cam belt?  (Skipped a few teeth, and back again?).  Water in fuel tank?  (Fuel module sucks up gas from bottom of tank, where water settles).  Question: were there any unusual weather conditions when the no run occurred?

Comment: My car came to a stop on the highway, but aside from this morning when my transmission seemed too cold to shift, my car has performed within specified parameters.

Comment: I drove that car on and off for 2 years without a further problem, just some bad leaks I still haven't tracked down!